# How to delete print

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the problem. In the following code, I wish to produce a 'moving cursor' effect. Here's the code:

```
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
time.sleep(2)
print ('virus_prevention.fix.virus.|attempt_enter')
time.sleep(2)
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
print ('virus_prevention.fix.virus|.attempt_enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
print ('virus_prevention.fix.viru|s.attempt.enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
print('virus_prevention.fix.vir|us.attempt.enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
print ('virus_prevention.fix.vi|rus.attempt.enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
print ('virus_prevention.fix.v|irus.attempt.enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
print ('virus_prevention.fix.|virus.attempt.enter')
time.sleep(2)
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
print ('virus_prevention.fix|virus.attempt.enter')
```

And this is the output:

```
[2K[1Gvirus_prevention.fix.virus.|attempt_enter
[2K[1Gvirus_prevention.fix.virus|.attempt_enter
[2K[1Gvirus_prevention.fix.viru|s.attempt.enter
[2K[1Gvirus_prevention.fix.vir|us.attempt.enter
[2K[1Gvirus_prevention.fix.vi|rus.attempt.enter
[2K[1Gvirus_prevention.fix.v|irus.attempt.enter
[2K[1Gvirus_prevention.fix.|virus.attempt.enter
```

And the `sys.stdout.write` doesn't really help. It just ends up with added text on the front of the current text. So if there are solutions anyone is willing to share (Python 3) please do. (I did have a solution which used repeatedly clearing the screen via `os.system('clear')`, which I don't really want to use.)

Comment: I've read this 4 times and I'm still confused. What are you asking for?

Comment: It seems that the used terminal codes aren't understood by the terminal. Better try something like "curses" which handles this for you.

Comment: I'm asking just for a simple solution where I can delete some print.

Answer (score 2):

`sys.stdout.write` is a good start, but you also need to pass a "carriage return" `'\r'` to jump to the beginning of the line. This will overwrite the old characters with the next call:

```
for i in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i)+'\r')
    time.sleep(1)
```

If the new line is shorter than the previous line, you will still see the additional characters of the previous line. As a fix you can add some additional spaces to overwrite them.

The main difference between `sys.stdout.write` and `print` is, that `print` will automatically append a linebreak (`\n`). This is why you see the `sys.stdout.write` infront of the next printed line.

Running this in an interactive Python session has some weird side effects, but it is fine if you use it in a Python script. Also, make sure not to have any other `print()` commands inbetween. This only works on the *current* line, and any `'\n'` creates a new line.

```
sys.stdout.write('virus_prevention.fix.virus.|attempt_enter\r')
time.sleep(2)
sys.stdout.write('virus_prevention.fix.virus|.attempt_enter\r')
print()  # create a linebreak at the end
```

Comment: wouldn't `print(str(i), end="\r")` do the same? And for more complex examples you also need to take care of adding spaces to be sure to clear the previous output..

Comment: 1) yes, see the other answer. 2) yes, I already mentioned that.

Comment: This would require manually writing the string as in OP's question, which is not required as shown in my answer

Comment: It sounded like you could not use print from your answer. Sorry, I just wanted to help, don't worry, maybe I misunderstood

Comment: @elgordorafiki I simply had not mind that you can pass `end` to `print`.

Comment: @Lucan Not manually writing a string was not part of the question. And from a technical point of view, it is not related on how to clear characters from the current line.

Comment: None of these work for Python 3. All it does is print even more lines because it's constantly printing the value of variable i.

Comment: @CubdGaming `str(i)` is just some simple example. Of course, you have to replace that with the string you want to print.

Comment: @CubdGaming I added a more explicit example, that should work just fine if you save to a .py file and run it.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to what you wish to achieve, you will need to adjust it to work with where you want the 'cursor' to show

```
import time

displayText = "Python"
character = '|'

for i in range(len(displayText)+1):
    print(displayText[:i] + character + displayText[i:], end='\r')
    time.sleep(.2)
input()
```

This will give the desired effect when executed via console/command prompt; but not through Python's IDLE Shell.

Comment: For some reason the function `\r` never works. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: `\r` only works if there are no further print commands (with implicit `\n`).

Comment: This is the output of your code @Lucan `|Python
P|ython
Py|thon
Pyt|hon
Pyth|on
Pytho|n
Python|`

Comment: @CubdGaming What OS do you use? "\r" should work fine on linux, but other systems may work differently.

Comment: It works fine on Windows too - but not if you run it through IDLE and possibly other IDE's because of the way they handle `\r`, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/15211) for it

Comment: I use Mac, but will soon move onto Windows.